# Offline Multiplayer for games in unity and in-app purchase

Tags: unity-game-engine, bluetooth, in-app-purchase, server, multiplayer

There's a few questions i would need help in. Firstly, i am creating  a multiple-player racing game in Unity for android and iOS. Something like Fun run & kart rider. How can i make them connecting to a device (which is the host) using Bluetooth or WiFi. Next, is it true that Google have free server for games to play multiple player ? Or is there any server that is free for my game ? Lastly, how do i create in-app purchase for my game in both Google play store and apple. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native functions provided by the services like on iOS its Game Center and on Android Google Play Games

There is a huge amount of informations about the way it works at the development centers from apple and google. If you wan't to get arround the native coding you can simply use some of the asset store plugings as some are cross platfrom and provide directly the functionalety you require.